# Solve the integral: $\int \frac{\sinh \left(x\right)-1}{2\sinh \left(x\right)+5\cosh \left(x\right)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{\sinh \left(x\right)-1}{2\sinh \left(x\right)+5\cosh \left(x\right)} dx$$
Please help me to solve this integral. At least the beginning of the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing everything in terms of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$, multiply numerator and denominator by $e^x$, then make the substitution $u = e^x$, $du = e^xdx = u dx$. Then do a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Thank you, I understand you!

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the hyperbolic functions to functions of $e^x$
Then I would do a substitution $u = e^x$
And I would have ratio of polynomials in terms of u.
Break that up into partial fractions.